# Reason for using `Any` over `AnyAsync` in async code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In the Microsoft tutorial for using ASP.NET Core with EF Core [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#the-puttodoitem-method), there is this sample code:

```cs
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutTodoItem(long id, TodoItem todoItem)
{
    if (id != todoItem.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    _context.Entry(todoItem).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!TodoItemExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return NoContent();
}

...

private bool TodoItemExists(long id)
{
    return _context.TodoItems.Any(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

Is there any reason we don't use the following function instead, given we are calling it from another async function?

```cs
private async Task<bool> TodoItemExistsAsync(long id)
{
    return await _context.TodoItems.AnyAsync(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: Probably because [before C# 6](https://dailydotnettips.com/using-await-in-a-catch-or-finally-block-in-c-6-0/) it was forbidden to use `await` in catch block.

Comment: ^^ Also, those examples do _not always_ follow best practices when it comes to stuff that is not directly the stuff that is to be shown an example of.

Comment: Maybe out of context, but its better to return the task directly instead of awaiting it. 

`private Task<bool> TodoItemExistsAsync(long id)
{
    return _context.TodoItems.AnyAsync(e => e.Id == id);
}`